# Saber quién hace cambios en base de datos mysql con php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una página web donde subes imágenes, pero primero tienes que pasar por un login, a alguien se le ocurre alguna manera de saber el usuario que sube la foto a mi base de datos mediante su Id, cabe recalcar que utilizo phpmyadmin y lo quiero hacer con php.

He investigado acerca de algo llamdo trigger, pero no estoy seguro que funcione para ver quien ha registrado en mi base de datos (https://www.siteground.es/kb/que-son-triggers-mysql-uso/)

Lo que he echo es utilizar este código, pero no me ha resultado en nada, si alguien está más especializado en el tema de trigger por favor ayúdeme

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TriggerUpdate ON dbo.t_pedidos FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO dbo.logTransacciones
(PK,ValorNuevo,ValorOriginal,FechaTrn, Usuario)
SELECT I.id,I.descripcion_anexo,D.descripcion_anexo, getdate(), system_user
FROM INSERTED I
INNER JOIN DELETED D ON
I.id = D.id
AND I.descripcion_anexo <> D.descripcion_anexo
```

Este es mi 
PROCESO_GUARDAR.PHP

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));

$query = "INSERT INTO tabla_imagen(nombre,Imagen) VALUES('$nombre', '$Imagen')";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

if($resultado){
    header("location:continuar.html");

}
else{
    echo "No se inserto";
}

?>
```

Index.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
    <title>Index de Imagenes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, intial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="banner">
  <img src="img/banner.jpg" alt="" class="banner__img">

   <center><br/><br/><br/>

       <div class="Cuadrado">
           <form action="proceso_guardar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="forma">

          <input class="Plh" type="text" required name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de la foto"/><br/><br/>    

          <input class="file" type="file" name="Imagen"/><br/><br/>      

         <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Aceptar">

         </form>
         </div>
         <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'mostrar.php'; " class="boton__mostrar animated infinite pulse" value="Ver ultimos 2 resultados!">


       </section>

   </center>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por medio del id del usuario? por favor lee [ask], edita y muestra que has hecho, que has investigado, dudas puntuales por que así parece basada en opiniones y sería motivo de cierre

Comment: Mejor señor ?? Espero que con esa informacion sea suficiente

Comment: En MySQL no existe el comando `ALTER TRIGGER`, [lee este tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/managing-trigger-in-mysql.aspx) que explica cómo funcionan, dice entre otras cosas: *Para modificar un `TRIGGER`, primero debe eliminarlo y volver a crearlo con el nuevo código. No hay declaración `ALTER TRIGGER` disponible en MySQL, por lo tanto, no puede modificar un `TRIGGER` existente como modifica otros objetos de la base de datos, como tablas, vistas y procedimientos almacenados.*

Comment: Debes mostrarnos el código que usas para subir la imagen, pues ahí sería donde puedes imputar el ID de usuario. También debes explicar la estructura de las tablas, cual es la relación con la imagen que se sube y en que tabla quieres almacenar el ID del usuario (nombrando también las relaciones existentes en esa tabla). Si nos explicas eso creo que te resultará fácil responder tu mismo la cuestión.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta, gracias, si ocupas otra cosa de mi codigo o tienes alugna duda, porfavor dime.

Comment: Hola @Jesús, ¿aún necesitas ayuda con esta cuestión? En ese caso, modifica tu pregunta incluyendo la estructura de la base de datos con algunos datos para realizar las pruebas (phpMyAdmin/Export). Saludos

Comment: Lo resolví hace bastante tiempo pero había olvidado agregar lo que hice, de todas maneras gracias.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Lo resolví de una manera más sencilla, al momento de hacer que el usuario hace el inicio de sesión guardo su User en una variable de sesión, después en cada modificación que hace también inserto esa variable donde tengo su User.